# Scanf_s function in oop principles

Tags: c++, oop, scanf

I have my home work in programming with oop. The task is:

> Create a base class "triangle", describing in it the functions of
> setting the parameters of the triangle, displaying them on the screen,
> finding the perimeter and area. Generate from it the class "isosceles
> triangle", redefining the functions for setting the parameters of the
> triangle and finding the area. The triangle is defined by the lengths
> of the sides. When entering parameters, be sure to check for the
> existence of a triangle.

So, my header file (classes.h):

```
class Triangle
{
public:
    Triangle();
    double a, b, c;
    virtual void EnterParam(); //enter parametr
    void DisplayParam(); //display parametr
    virtual double Area();
    double Perimetr();
};
class IsoscelesTriangle : public Triangle
{
public:
    IsoscelesTriangle();
    virtual void EnterParam(); //enter parametr
    virtual double Area();
};
```

Then define some function (classes.cpp):

```
#include "classes.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
double p, s, t;
Triangle::Triangle()
{

}
void Triangle::EnterParam()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter first side: a = ");
        a = scanf_s("%f", &t);
        printf("\nEnter second side: b = ");
        b = scanf_s("%f", &t);
        printf("\nEnter third side: c = ");
        c = scanf_s("%f", &t);
        if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a)
            printf("Triangle exists\n");
        else printf("Error!!! Repeat enter data! \n");
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (a + b < c && a + c < b && b + c < a);
}
void Triangle::DisplayParam()
{
    printf("Sides lenghts: a=%f b=%f c=%f \n", a, b, c);
}
double Triangle::Area()
{
    //calculate half-perimetr
    p = (a + b + c) / 2;
    //calculate area
    s = pow(p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c), 0.5);
    return s;
}
double Triangle::Perimetr()
{
    return a + b + c;
}

IsoscelesTriangle::IsoscelesTriangle()
{
    a = b;
}

void IsoscelesTriangle::EnterParam()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter first side: a = ");
        a = scanf_s("%f", &t);
        printf("\nEnter second side: b = ");
        b = scanf_s("%f", &t);
        printf("\nEnter third side: c = ");
        c = scanf_s("%f", &t);
        if ( a == b)
            printf("Triangle is IsoscelesTriangle\n");
        else printf("Error!!! Repeat enter data! \n");
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (a != b);
}

double IsoscelesTriangle::Area()
{
    Triangle::Area();
    s = c / 4 * sqrt(pow(4 * a, 2) - pow(c, 2));
    return s;
}
```

Finally main part (mainfile.cpp):

```
#include "classes.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    Triangle tr;
    IsoscelesTriangle isotr;
    Triangle *ptr = NULL;
    int key1, key2;
    //setlocale(0, "RUS"); // обеспечиваем вывод в консольное окно символов кириллицы
    do //choose type of triangle
    {
        printf("\n1 - arbitrary triangle\n");
        printf("2 - isosceles triangle\n");
        printf("ESC - escape\n");
        printf("Your choise: \n");
        key1 = _getch();
        switch (key1)
        {
        case '1':
            ptr = &tr;
            break;
        case '2':
            ptr = &isotr;
            break;
        }
        if (key1 != 27)
        {
            do //choose action for triangle
            {
                printf("\n1 - enter parametr\n");
                printf("2 - display parametr\n");
                printf("3 - calculate area\n");
                printf("ESC - escape\n");
                printf("Your choise: \n");
                key2 = _getch();
                switch (key2)
                {
                case '1': ptr->EnterParam(); break;
                case '2': ptr->DisplayParam(); break;
                case '3': printf("Area is: %.2lf\n", ptr->Area());
                    break;
                }
            } while (key2 != 27);
        }
    } while (key1 != 27);
    return 0; 
}
```

When I try to display the parametres I have the next parametr of sides.
[image]

I enter next parametr: a = 3, b = 4, c = 5. And get a = 1, b = 1, c = 1.
Where I did the mistake?
Sorry for long code

Comment: `a = scanf_s("%f", &t)` Try `%lf` for double. Why are you using [tag:C] functions for [tag:C++] I/O?

Comment: `a = scanf_s("%f", &t);` The `scanf` function returns how many successful scans there were. Try `scanf_s("%f", &a);`, etc.

Comment: User input is the least of the problems here. The entire implementation fails to meet the assignment's requirements. The programming assignment requires you to define "the functions of setting the parameters of the triangle", and not "write scanf to set the class members". It's quite clear that the class should have ***no*** public members, and only public methods. The assignment itself is also rather poor. The proper way to initialize the class is via its constructor. That's what it's for. And not by constructing a completely uninitialized class, and rely on class methods to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. @Johny Mopp I try to use &a, but it`s not working. As I understand I must to rewrite the code.

Comment: I highly recommend using C++ I/O streams.  For example, `scanf` and `printf` families can't handle the `std::string` type nor custom classes.

Comment: Re: `I try to use &a, but it`s not working` - could you please show what did you try? Do you still have `a = scanf(...`?

Comment: People, I apologize for my stupidity. I use c++ I/O and everything is working!!! Thanks for you all!!